# How to make File Open dialog more similar to Finder window?

Tags: mojave

In previous versions of macOS, the File Open dialog had a "Show sidebar" button, "Show items as" and "Group items by" radio buttons in the toolbar.

[image: "Old" File Open dialog]

In Mojave (not sure in which version this was changed), they're hidden under a hamburger menu:
[image: Mojave's File Open dialog]

Is there some way to make the File Open more similar to the Finder window, like in previous macOS versions?

Comment: Do you see the buttons if you switch to Column view (from Icon view in your screenshot)?

Comment: @fsb no, but the icon changes (what I thought was a "hamburger" icon is in fact a "list" icon)

Answer (score 6):

Natively, without the use of third-party software<sup>1</sup>, no, the **Toolbar** of a **Open File…** window is not customizable in **macOS Mojave**, and its layout was changed from what was the norm in previous versions. It was not customizable in previous versions as well.

That said, you can still use the *default* **Finder** *keyboard shortcuts* to manipulate the window's **view** instead of using the **button menu** on the **Toolbar**.

For **Hide Sidebar** / **Show Sidebar** use: **⌥⌘S**  <sub>(Option-Command-S)</sub>

**Show items as:**

- as Icons  **⌘1**
- as List   **⌘2**
- as Columns **⌘3**

<sub>Note that other *default* **Finder** *keyboard shortcuts* may apply; however, I only tried the ones already mentioned.</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> Per a comment, there is [Default Folder X](https://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/), $34.95 USD, that may have some functionality that could be useful.

<sub>Note that I have no affiliation with its developer nor have I used it. At that price, I probably wouldn't either.</sub>

Comment: Also there is a utility that lets you change the defaults of this, been around a long time. I've never used it but know of a lot who do: https://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/

Comment: I've been using DefaultFolder since System 8 or 9 - it's worth the money.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've had no issues using the default Open File… window through macOS High Sierra and the only thing I do not like in macOS Mojave, in this particular case, is not having the individual buttons for the Show items as, but with ⌘1, ⌘2, ⌘3 for that, and ⌥⌘S for the Hide/Show Sidebar, I'll save the $34.95 USD. I'm sure the app has lots of features, but for me I'm not going to spend the money for this particular issue. That said, it can be tried free for 30 days, so maybe I'll take a closer look at it, or not.